# addObject to NSMutableArray not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In short, I want my `tableView` to show events (eg. football matches) that are happening Today. Therefore, I want to add those dictionaries that match to a `NSMutableArray` by use of `addObject`. I've tried it with this code, but the `NSMutableArray` does not show anything:

```
self.Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"matches" ofType:@"plist"]];

matchesToday = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
match = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for  (int i=0; i<[Array count]; i++) {
        NSDate *datum = [[Array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
        components = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:datum];
        NSDate *otherDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

        if([today isEqualToDate:otherDate]) {

            //do stuff
            [matchesToday addObject:match];

        NSLog(@"%i, %@", i, otherDate);
        NSLog(@"Match is today");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Match is not today");
    }
    }
NSLog(@"%@", matchesToday);
}
```

The plist is an array of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
<array>
    <dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2011-12-13T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>titel</key>
    <string>Tilburg - Oss</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2011-12-13T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>titel</key>
    <string>Amsterdam - Roosendaal</string>
    </dict> 
</array>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your code, `match` is nothing but an empty dictionary. You don't do anything with your `match` dictionary at any point after you `alloc` and `init` it. If it's in the `// do something` comment block, please add that.

Comment: No, I haven't done anything with 'match' indeed. I want 'match' to correspond to the dictionaries from the plist. This must be the problem. I guess I should do something like `NSMutableArray *match = [Array..... ` Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be adding the individual item from Array inside the date test if statement with the following line:

```
[matchesToday addObject:[Array objectAtIndex:i]];
```

At the point that this code executes, match is just an empty mutable array.